# Convert any JSON to name/value pairs

Tags: python, json

I have a source JSON that can be in any potential format. For storage & processing purposes, I'd like to save this data in 2 column format.

For example, I'd like the following JSON:

```
"record" {
  "name1": "value1",
  "name2": "value2",
  "parameters": {
    "param": {},
    "paramSet": {
      "items": [{
        "id": "id1"
      }, {
        "id": "id2"
      }]
    }
  }
}
```

To be converted to the following CSV-like format:

```
record:name1 , "value1"
record:name2 , "value2"
record:parameters:param , ""
record:parameters:paramSet:items#0:id , "id1"
record:parameters:paramSet:items#1:id , "id2"
```

My questions are:

1. Is there a formal name for this transformation (so that I can search better).
2. Is there a standard or convention for representing JSON in a 2-column format like this?
3. Are there any libraries in Python that can do this for me?
4. Are there libraries on other major programming languages that will make it easier to implement this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Implementing such a transformation in Python would take a few dozen lines at most. I'm not sure why you even consider switching to a different programming language for the sake of solving this. It's not a hard problem.

Comment: BTW-Your json is invalid

Comment: Thanks, I realize this could be easy to code but I wanted to avoid looking at the encoding of property names/ids and other edge cases that may arise. (Hence my question about whether there is a standard name for this type of transformation).

Answer (score 1):

First I made json correct:

```
{
  "record": {
    "name1": "value1",
    "name2": "value2",
    "parameters": {
      "param": {},
      "paramSet": {
        "items": [
          {
            "id": "id1"
          },
          {
            "id": "id2"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Next some code for recursive mocking json

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import json


class Thing(object):
    data = ''
    output = []

    def __init__(self, file_name):
        with open(file_name) as data_file:
            self.data = json.load(data_file)

    def mock(self):
        for (i, item) in enumerate(self.data):
            if type(self.data[item]) == dict:
                self._recursive(self.data[item], item)
        for (i, data) in enumerate(self.output):
            print(data)

    def _recursive(self, request_data, path):
        for (i, item) in enumerate(request_data):
            if type(request_data[item]) == dict:
                if len(request_data[item]) > 0:
                    path2 = "{}:{}".format(path, item)
                    self._recursive(request_data[item], path2)
                else:
                    self.output.append("{}:{}, \"\"".format(path, item))
            elif type(request_data[item]) == list:
                for (j, list_item) in enumerate(request_data[item]):
                    path2 = "{}:{}#{}".format(path, item, j)
                    self._recursive(request_data[item][j], path2)
            else:
                self.output.append("{}:{}, {}".format(path, item, request_data[item]))

thing = Thing("input.json")
thing.mock()
```

Following code will output:

```
record:name1, value1
record:name2, value2
record:parameters:paramSet:items#0:id, id1
record:parameters:paramSet:items#1:id, id2
record:parameters:param, ""
```